# How to insert data if your column name is abc_data.(Here dot)?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I want to insert data in one table and one of my column Name is `abc_data.(here dot)`.

I wrote

```
 insert into tablename (abc_data. , data1) 
 values (@abc, @def);
```

and I get an error:

> Error: Incorrect Syntax near ','

I am suspecting the error to be in `abc_data.(here dot)` here in column name.

Comment: remove the dot after  abc_data

Comment: Read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html enclose column name in back ticks OR change column name to valid identifier which would not need backticks (remove .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  avoid dot in columns name because the dot is used  as oject name saparator in fully qualified  name

```
insert into tablename(abc_data , data1) values(@abc,@def);
```

anyway if you have a column name with dot then in mysql use backtics for avoid this error

```
insert into tablename(`abc_data.` , data1) values(@abc,@def);
```

Comment: I am using Inbuild DB in Visual Studio 2012. I tried your suggestions but it again shows me error  [Incorrect syntax near `'`.] . Any other alternative

Comment: you need backtics and not single quote  or change your column name and avoid dot

Comment: backtics in windows  are  alt + 96

Comment: Thank You My Friend. It works!! :)